# New column in ng2-smart-table created from Object datatype

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

Does anyone know how to create new column from Object datatype ?
How I able to to do it ?
Code of my setting and data below for more clearly understanding
Thanks in Advance!
    private settings = {

```
columns: {
      firstName: {
        title: 'First name',
        type: 'text'
      },
      lastName: {
        title: 'Last name',
        type: 'text'
      },
      userType: {  
        // This is correct way only when there is string in response from API named - userType
        // But when I'm trying to type something like - userType.value i get an error 
        title: 'User type',
        type: 'text'
      },
}
```

data from API:

```
.......
    {
      firstName: 'Jacob',
      lastName: '',
      middleName: '',
      userType: {value: 'superAdmin', display: 'Super Administrator'},
      login: '',
      password: '',
      phoneNumber: '066-233-77-34',
      city: 'Rome',
      address: 'someStreet',
      salary: '0',
    },
......
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a valuePrepareFunction property on the column, so that you could specify a formatter for a value before it will be inserted in a cell like this:

```
{
your_column: {
  title: 'some',
  valuePrepareFunction: (value) => { return value === 1 ? 'true' : 'false' }
}
}
```

I got an idea invoke myCustomFunc in valuePrepareFunction. By myCustomFunc I redefinition value to what i need to get